# python format and display non ASCII characters

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to print the `£` sign, but I cannot seem to do this using the format() methodology.I'm trying the following:

```
curr_prefix = u"\xA3"
print "{}".format(curr_prefix)
```

But I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of a squillion other questions on printing Unicode in Python. Read them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print u"{}".format(curr_prefix)`